# $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a function $f(x)$ then does it follow that the limit function $f(x)$ is also uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

If a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a function $f(x)$, and if each $f_n(x)$ is uniformly continuous, then does it follow that the limit function $f(x)$ is also uniformly continuous.

My try:

Since each $f_n(x)$ is uniformly continuous, we have $|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x_m)| < \epsilon/3$, for ....

and $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a function $f(x)$, we have $|f_n(x_m) - f(x_m)| < \epsilon/3$, for...

Thus, $$|f(x_m) - f(x_n)| \leq |f_n(x_m) - f(x_m)|+|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x_m)|+|f(x_n) - f_n(x_n)| \\< \epsilon/3 +\epsilon/3 +\epsilon/3 = \epsilon$$

Thus $f(x)$ is also uniformly continuous.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Not quite. What are $x_n, x_m$? The idea is right, at least it is possibly right, but the way you wrote it down is at least incomplete.

Comment: At the end of the day, to show $f$ is uniformly continuous, you need to show for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta >0 $ *independent of $x$, such that $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.  So your proof should always start off by saying something like "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary..." and then show how you get your $\delta$.  You do have the main step of the proof down -- to use the triangle inequality as you did.  Basically, since $f_{n}$ is uniformly continuous, we get a delta that doesn't depend on $x$ from there.  Also, $f$ converges uniformly, so...

Comment: ...choosing $N$ large enough, we can get that $|f_{n}(x) - f(x)|< \epsilon/3$ for every $x$.  So, the $\delta$ that worked for the uniform continuity of $f_{n}$ will be good enough (i.e., it is the right choice of $\delta$) to prove uniform continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my two comments, my proof would look like:

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then since $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| + |f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(y)| + |f_{n}(y) - f(y)|$, choose $\delta>0$ (independent of $x$) such that the middle term is $< \epsilon/3$ -- we can do this since $f_{n}$ is uniformly continuous for each $n$.  Then letting $N$ be large enough such that for every $x$, the first and last terms are each $< \epsilon/3$ (we can do this by uniform convergence), we get that if $|x - y| < \delta$, $|f(x) - f(x)| < 3( \epsilon/3) = \epsilon$, and we are done.